# how to add a project to a specific permission scheme?

Tags: jira

How can I add a project into a specific permission scheme?

Here is the permission scheme that I would like my project to have

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick Answer

It’s in the Admin section. You have the ability to pick which projects are associated to which permission schemes (similar to workflows, workflow schemes, etc...).

### Supporting Documentation

[Here is a great write up created by Atlassian that explains this in more detail.](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/manage-project-permissions/#)